# given these Axiom, do we have multiple different set of natural number?

Tags: analysis, natural-numbers

I am trying to understand what is the meaning of Axiom 2.1of a book.

```
Is "0 is a natural number" same as "the origin is 0 and 0 is unique"
```

The reason I am asking is as follow.

Given:

```
Axiom 2.1: 0 is a natural number
Axiom 2.2. If n is a natural number, then n++ is also a natural number.
Axiom 2.3. 0 is not the successor of any natural number; i.e., we have n++ = 0 for every natural number 
Axiom 2.4. Different natural numbers must have different successors; i.e., if n, m are natural numbers and n = m, then n++ = m++. Equivalently2, if n++ = m++, then we must have n = m.
```

Trying to transform the "natural number object" from [natural number: name and successor] to [natural number: name and ancestor].
Is this transformation valid, however? Does every natural number beside 0 have an ancestor?
Can we define multiple different set of natural number start from different origin such that not natural number beside 0 have an ancestor?

Comment: Yes, every natural number besides zero has an ancestor. Yes, you can define natural number any way you want to, but if you don't define it the same way everyone else does, how can we ever talk to each other?

Comment: Mathematics is no Pippi Langstrumpf world where everyone can define everything how he/she wants, but there is no convention about whether $0$ is a natural number. Both possibilities are allowed , and in a paper or book it must be clarified which possibility is chosen. That there is only one "0" is obvious , proving this is like shooting rockets on ants , of course one can prove it nevertheless, if one actually wants.

Comment: Axioms 2.1 - 2.4 apply to any non-empty well-order $(X,\le)$ that has no maximum, if you define $n++:=\min\{x\in X\,:\, x>n\}$. So whatever you're trying to do to reformulate $\Bbb N$, you can't refer to just those 4 axioms.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio He also defined a succession operation. Meaning that the set that you have chosen ($\min\{ x \in X : x > n \}$) with the $k++$ binary operation, would be isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Pastudent I don't understand your point. If you define $0:=\min X$, "n is a natural number" := "$n\in X$" and $n++:=\min\{x\in X\,:\, x>n\}$, then 2.1-2.4 are true. (aside from the fact that 2.4 contains mistakes of logic, but let's say that it says the thing that it states twice out of three times)

Comment: @Pastudent Also, in the OP the ++ operation is unary.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio My point was to say : if your Set, with you definition satisfies all the Peano axioms (which almost what the OP is using (he is missing to define the whole Set)), then yes, it would define natural numbers. If your set satisfied induction, then the subset $K \subset X$ satisfying all the axioms, could be identified with the natural numbers.

Comment: @Pastudent I can't know if the person who asked has the minimal-saturated-subset construction in mind.